# Once she was my hope

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Every day my eyes they open just a little more
>   Every day my heart it darkens, shrivels to the core
>   Till finally, dried up, defeated, I fall in pieces to the floor
>
> Once she was my hope, my life she tried to save
>   Slowly her will did drain, everything she gave
>   Alas her love it was in vain, now she is my grave

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are a

> Flower

And she is

> A vase of water.

Every day my eyes they open just a little more

> Flower petals open as you blossom.

Every day my heart it darkens, shrivels to the core

> As time passes, you also shrivel.

Till finally, dried up, defeated, I fall in pieces to the floor

> Bit by bit, your petals will fall to the floor.

Once she was my hope, my life she tried to save

> A vase of water will prolong a flower's life, temporarily.

Slowly her will did drain, everything she gave

> Her will is the water she provides.

Alas her love it was in vain, now she is my grave

> The vase is the final resting place of the flower.